# How can I delete bogus links under /admin/structure?

Tags: navigation, 9

I am running Drupal 9.3.4.  I see four bogus links under /admin/structure. See the screen shot below.  These were paths used by the Context module that were deleted. They are no longer listed under /admin/structure/context, but now they show up under /admin/structure. I assume that these are orphaned records in the database.  Does anyone know where they would live in the database and how I can delete them, perhaps using drush?

[image: Screen shot of /admin/structure]